# How to find a word in a text and change his colour keeping all other settings

Tags: swift

I want to search a particular word in a text and change his colour but I want as well to keep all other settings (font, label colour, etc) of the initial label. I tried with following code. Result is that the word colour effectively changes as I want but all initial parameters from my label are moving back to some standard like (sentence back in black, font type and size back to system, etc). I don't understand why the whole sentence is back to standard and how to keep it.

```
    // highlight word colour of example
    
    exampleTextView.textColor = UIColor.blue
    
    let color1 = UIColor.red
    let textToFind = newWordQuiz
    
            
    let attrsString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string:exampleTextView.text!)

    
    // search for word occurrence
    let range = (exampleTextView.text! as NSString).range(of: textToFind, options: .caseInsensitive)
    if (range.length > 0) {
        attrsString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor,value:color1,range:range)
    }

            
    // set attributed text
    exampleTextView.attributedText = attrsString
```

Comment: `NSMutableAttributedString(string:exampleTextView.text!)` -> `NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString:exampleTextView.attributedText!)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example for you based on userInterfaceStyle, the explanation is in comment lines:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {

let textV = UITextView()
let textToFind = "Are You Find Me?"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    textV.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textV.text = "I want to search a particular word in a text and change his colour but I want as well to keep all other settings (font, label colour, etc) of the initial label. I tried with following code. Result is that the word colour effectively changes as I want but all initial parameters from my label are moving back to some standard like, Are You Find Me? (sentence back in black, font type and size back to system, etc). I don't understand why the whole sentence is back to standard and how to keep it."

    // setup constraints
    view.addSubview(textV)
    textV.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    textV.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    textV.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    textV.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    
    setHighlighted(tv: textV, text: textV.text, with: textToFind)
}

func setHighlighted(tv: UITextView, text: String, with search: String) {
    let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text, attributes: [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white, .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .semibold)]) //set attributes
    let range = NSString(string: text).range(of: search, options: .caseInsensitive) // Set range
    
    // set highlightColor and highlightFontColor based on userInterfaceStyle
    let highlightColor = traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark ? UIColor.yellow /*highlight bg Color*/: UIColor.white /*normal bg Color*/
    let highlightFontColor = traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark ? UIColor.red /*highlight font Color*/ : UIColor.black /*normal font Color*/
    
    let highlightedAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.backgroundColor: highlightColor, .foregroundColor: highlightFontColor, .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .semibold)] // set highlight attributes
    
    attributedText.addAttributes(highlightedAttributes, range: range) // Assign highlight attribute to attributedText
    tv.attributedText = attributedText // assign attributedText to TextView
  }
}
```

This is the result:

[image]